# Custom-built virtualized grid component - preventing empty space above/to the left of sticky cells when scrolling quickly

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently in the process of rewriting a custom-built virtualized grid component which allows for both a given number of sticky columns and sticky rows. It's built based off of bvaughn's [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) with a decent portion of logic and UI removed or modified to meet our needs.

The component has 4 layers-

- Outer container - a box which grows or shrinks to fill its parent's bounds, and stores those dimensions in state, using flex property '1 1 auto'.
- Scroll container - a container sized based on both the content's dimensions and the parent's dimensions with overflow set to 'auto' to allow for scrolling. As the user scrolls, the indices of the cells which should be visible are recalculated and will re-render if the scroll position exceeds the position of those cells.
- Estimated size container - An estimated cell height/width is used to create a container that should more-or-less match the size of all cells as if they were all rendered at once, which will then overflow the scroll container. As the user scrolls, the estimate will become more accurate as the actual height/width of the cells are cached.
- Visible Grid - the current range of cells to be rendered, based on calculations made while scrolling. The children of this div (the array of cells) will be re-defined and re-render as those indices change (keys are provided to these memoized cells to ensure cells which are already visible don't re-render).

Simplified JSX for the component:

```html
<Box // Outer Container
  ref={outerRef}
  onLayout={handleLayout}
  ...otherOuterBoxProps
>
    <div // Scroll Container
        ref={scrollContainerRef}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        style={{
            overflow: 'auto',
            ...otherScrollContainerStyles
        }}
    >
        <div // Estimated Size Container
            style={{
                  height: estimatedTotalHeight,
                  pointerEvents: isScrolling ? 'none' : undefined,
                  position: 'relative',
                  width: estimatedTotalWidth
             }}
        >
            <div // Visible Grid
                children={cells}
                style={{
                    height: heightStopOffset + calculatedRowHeight - heightStartOffset
                    width: widthStopOffset + calculatedColumnWidth - widthStartOffet
                    top: heightStartOffset,
                    left: widthStartOffset,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    ...otherVisibleGridStyles
                }}
```

Sticky cells themselves are provided one or both these style properties depending on if they are included in the range of sticky columns and/or rows:

```js
{ // if part of a sticky column
   left: getColumnOffset( cellWidth, columnIndex, instanceProps ), // horizontal position of the cell in the visible grid
   position: 'sticky'
}
{ // if part of a sticky row
  top: getRowOffset( cellHeight, rowIndex, instanceProps ), // vertical position of the cell in the visible grid
  position: 'sticky'
}
```

This essentially causes them to stick to their known position in grid.

While this works fine when scrolling down or right, the issue is that when quickly scrolling up or left while new cells are rendered, there's a visible gap between the top/left of the scroll container and the top/left of the grid, and the sticky cells don't stick to the correct position until the updated visible grid has been committed.

[The undesired effect in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se1JN.png)

Is there potentially a way I could, while the grid re-renders, have these cells appear positioned to the absolute top/left of the scroll container as opposed to the visible grid container? Of course that would mean the top and left style properties assigned to them would need to change, but I'm curious if there's a way I can have those conditionally set while in the short span of time while re-rendering the grid.